# Calendario PrimeVue desde CDN no reconoce las Props

Tags: primevue

Estoy tratando **de usar el componente de Calendar pero al querer usar disabledDays="[5,6]" no detecta la props**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.